# Advaita Vedanta and Zen Buddhism - Similarities and Differences

Tags: buddhism, hinduism

I asked a question about Zen Buddhism a few months ago, which called Mahayana (where Zen comes from) a fusion of Hinduism and Classic Buddhism. This would suggest strong similarities between Zen and specific forms of Hinduism.

In my study of both Zen and Advaita Vedanta I've found that the concepts are indeed very similar, however I'd like to clarify the ways in which they are distinct philosophies

So my question: which attributes of the two philosophies are the same? Which attributes are different?

Comment: Zen is part of the broader Mahayana school and was influenced by prior Mahayana schools like [Madhyamaka](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/madhyamaka/) and [Yogacara](http://www.acmuller.net/yogacara/articles/intro.html) (both influenced by earlier [Abhidharma](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abhidharma/) teachings). It was also influenced by the [Huayan](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/buddhism-huayan/) Mahayana tradition in China. For similarities between Advaita and Mahayana as a whole there are references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_influences_on_Advaita_Vedanta).

Comment: Part of the Mahayana tradition of Buddhism. The primary difference is the nature of the individual 'soul' (a Western term) prior to liberation. Advaita asserts that there are individual jivas that go from birth to birth prior to liberation, moksha. Mahayana asserts that it is essentially just a wave with the impetus of the prior life(s). The final liberation in both is the same as is the nature of final liberation. See https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey#donate_dropdown